# How do I print this elif string

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create a guessing game and it works all well. However, I want to include a part where if a user puts a number above 100, you are told that your choice should be less than 100. The code below doesn't seem to do that. What am I doing wrong?

```
import random
comGuess = random.randint(0,100)
while True:
    userGuess = int(input("Enter your guess  :"))
    if userGuess > comGuess:
            print ("Please go lower")
    elif userGuess < comGuess:
            print ("Please go higher")
    elif userGuess > (100):
            print ("Your choice should be less than 100")
    elif userGuess <1:
            print ("Your choice should be less than 100")
    else:
        print ("Great, you got it right")
        break
```

Comment: What variable are you trying to print?

Comment: Try with `userGuess > 100` and use `raw_input` if on python 2. Also the check for over 100 should be performed immediately after the input, by a separate `if`

Answer (score 3):

Any number above 100 will definitely be higher than the target, and enter the `if` condition. Any number below 1 will definitely be lower than the target, and enter the first `elif`. If you want to validate the user's input, you should do that **before** comparing it to `comGuess`:

```
if userGuess > (100):
        print ("Your choice should be less than 100")
elif userGuess <1:
        print ("Your choice should be less than 100")
elif userGuess > comGuess:
        print ("Please go lower")
elif userGuess < comGuess:
        print ("Please go higher")    
else:
    print ("Great, you got it right")
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first `if` statement is catching *anything* greater than comGuess, even if it's also over 100, and so the `elif userGuess > (100)` that comes later never gets a chance to fire. Either move that `elif` up, or change the first `if` statement to something like `if (userGuess > comGuess) and (userGuess <= 100)`.